# Where is maven respository for jsf mojarra 2.3.18?

Tags: maven, gradle, jsf, jsf-2.2, mojarra

Where is maven respository for jsf mojarra 2.3.18?

The maven center has mojarra 2.4 that does not exist on github mojarra project. but the maven center does not have version 2.3.18 that is the latest release for 2.3.x. where is the version 2.4 coming from on the maven center?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has moved from the [`javax.faces`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/javax.faces) artifact to the [`jakarta.faces`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/jakarta.faces) artifact. You need to update the `<artifactId>` accordingly.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.faces</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.18</version>
</dependency>
```

Noted should be that [Mojarra 2.4 should absolutely not be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58269503).

Comment: Is this artifact API or impl? Thanks

Comment: Mojarra is the impl. JSF is the API. You specifically asked for Mojarra :) This specific impl artifact has the API also bundled.

Comment: @BalusC can you please check some of my recent jsf questions regarding upgrading a JSF application. not getting any leads from anywhere. kind of stuck! :( would really appreciate some guidance. Thanks!