JSF 2.3.9 and Fortify Warnings (Reflected XSS and Directory Traversal)
I am using JSF 2.3.9 and Fortify and I am getting the following warnings:
1. Reflected XSS:

faces/context/PartialViewContextImpl.java in Eclipse Mojarra, as used in Mojarra for Eclipse EE4J before 2.3.10 and Mojarra JavaServer Faces before 2.2.20, allows Reflected XSS because a client window field is mishandled.
2. Directory Traversal:
Directory traversal in Eclipse Mojarra before 2.3.14 allows attackers to read arbitrary files via the loc parameter or con parameter.
I couldn't understand the reason for these warnings and how to solve them. I need help from JSF and security experts.

I just searched the problem and found nothing. I can't solve it.

I'm not understanding which part of the report you aren't understanding. You basically just need to upgrade Mojarra 2.3.9 to latest available 2.3.x version. The report basically mentions 2 issues which are fixed in 2.3.10 resp. 2.3.14. So obviously you need a minimum of 2.3.14 but the latest is always the best choice in order to ensure that all last known bugs are fixed.

Even though I upgraded the Javax faces library to 2.4.0 and added the secure version of the mojarra-parent dependency to my library, the problem was not solved. That's why I didn't understand.

2.4.0 is not the latest available 2.3.x version. That's currently 2.3.21. Moreover: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58269503
